# Can't access method in Vue Single File Component with Jest when using <script setup>

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, vue-jest

I'd like to test specific methods in my Vue Single File Components using Jest. I'm using Vue 3 with the Composition API, and I would like to use the `<script setup>` approach but it appears to prevent this.

**This works:**

Component:

```html
<script>
export default {
  setup() {
    const testMethod = function(input) {
      return input + 1;
    };
    return { testMethod };
  },
};
</script>
```

Test:

```js
test('should be 2', () => {
  expect(TestComponent.setup().testMethod(1)).toBe(2); // success
});
```

**This doesn't work:**

Component:

```html
<script setup>
const testMethod = function(input) {
  return input + 1;
};
</script>
```

Test:

```js
test('should be 2', () => {
  expect(TestComponent.setup().testMethod(1)).toBe(2); // TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'expose' of 'undefined' as it is undefined.
  expect(TestComponent.testMethod(1)).toBe(2); // TypeError: _testComponent.default.testMethod is not a function
});
```

Is there another way to accomplish this, or is accessing the methods within the component not possible with the `<script setup>` approach?

**Edit:** Specifically looking for solutions that don't require mounting the gadget with something like vue-test-utils.

Comment: Side note: I did try using defineExpose but it didn't appear to help. https://v3.vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#defineexpose

Comment: Composition API isn't suited to test the implementation, instead consider Vue Testing Library. It was the same in React ecosystem.

Answer (score 3):

The bindings declared in `<script setup>` are hidden by default, but you can expose any of them to the component instance with [`defineExpose()`](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#defineexpose):

```html
// MyComponent.vue
<script setup>
const testMethod = function(input) {
  return input + 1;
};

defineExpose({
  testMethod
})
</script>
```

Then in your test, access the exposed bindings via [`wrapper.vm`](https://next.vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/#vm) (the component instance from the `@vue/test-utils` wrapper):

```js
// MyComponent.spec.js
import MyComponent from '@/components/MyComponent.vue'

test('should be 2', () => {
  const wrapper = shallowMount(MyComponent)
  expect(wrapper.vm.testMethod(1)).toBe(2)
})
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-test-exposed-props-from-script-setup?file=tests/unit/example.spec.js)

Comment: I was actually specifically looking for methods that didn't require mounting the component and `@vue/test-utils`. Do you know if that's possible? Thanks!

Comment: AFAIK, that's not possible. The `<script setup>` declarations are closed by design (based on the docs for `defineExpose`). A workaround would be to move those methods into a lib file that could be imported by your component's `<script setup>` and by your tests.

Answer (score 0):

if you use the wrapper of the mount method from vue test `@vue/test-utils`. Then just call the methods using `(wrapper.vm as any)` it works. Only the typescript compiler is unable to recognize and raise the error as `property does not exist` but when you try using something like below it works.

Eg: `(wrapper.vm as any).someMethod()`

Answer (score 0):

I am also facing the same issue. below ways can help us to resolve this

1. `(wrapper.vm as any)._setupProxy.someMethod`

   not sure using `_setupProxy` is the proper way or not.
2. ```
   import {shallowMount,createLocalVue} from '@vue/test-utils';
   import VueCompositionApi from '@vue/composition-api';

   const localVue = createLocalVue()
   localVue.use(VueCompositionApi)
   shallowMount(require('./component.vue').default, {
     localVue,
   });
   ```